# why dart method chain with cascade doesn't work with setter methods?

Tags: dart

I have some model classes like this one:

```
class Environment {
  String _oidClientId;
  String _oidIssuerUrl;
  get issuerUrl => _oidIssuerUrl;
  set issuerUrl(String pIssuerUrl) => this._oidIssuerUrl = pIssuerUrl;
  get clientId => _oidClientId;
  set clientId(String pClientID) => this._oidClientId = pClientID;

}
```

I've tried to create an instance and use cascade to set values on it:

```
var env = Environment.dev()
  ..clientId("my.id.public")
  ..issuerUrl("https://demo.myserver.com")
```

But the compiler is given me this error:

```
Undefined name 'clientId'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.dart(undefined_identifier)
```

If I change the code, renaming the getter(due a duplicated name) and turn the setter into a `void clientId(String pClientID)` then the compiler doesn't complains. but I would prefer not doing this.
Am I missing something?

Comment: You don't need the getters and setters here at all. Just write `class Environment { String issuerUrl; String clietntId; }`. That's sufficient and the recommended way to write such a class. The getter/setters are unnecessary (unless you actually do something more than reading and storing in the getter in the real code).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misused the setters. The following code should work:

```
var env = Environment.dev()
  ..clientId = "my.id.public"
  ..issuerUrl = "https://demo.myserver.com";
```

Comment: Indeed it worked ! 
seems that my java history is tricking me :)
thanks